# .NET Console APP MySQL 8 The program has exited with code -1073740940 (0xc0000374)

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net

I have moved my vb.net/C# code to Azure hosting (Server 2019) and am now using MySQL v8 vs previously MySQL v5.6, with Oracle ODBC Connector 8.  All of my concole apps connects and reads fine.  But when there are inserts/updates/delete queries, VS 2019 console hangs, then closes.  It can be after 5 records, or 100s that this behavior happens.  It seems like the database connection is lost, but I can't figure out if that is the issue or not.  I have MSBuild set to Diagnostic, and this is the only error I receive:

```
The program has exited with code -1073740940 (0xc0000374)
```

VS code has no external dlls, no 3rd party. Very simple odbc connection.  VS debut and ODBC driver are both x86.

I need help with VS debugging to find where the problem exists, and hopefully how to resolve it.

I have ran a trace with ODBC driver with no helpful data provided.  I have excluded our Antivirus from the project folder with the EXE exists.  I have installed MYSQL 8 on the localhost, used both 64bit and 32bit MySQL and ODBC drivers, same results.

Comment: Why Oracle ODBC Connector 8 when you're connecting to a MySQL server?  Why not just use the MySQL .net Client?

Comment: I have always used the MySQL ODBC connector with zero issues.  I will try the .NET Client, but I need to understand why this is not working.

Comment: Your question says Oracle ODBC Connector, your comment says MySQL ODBC Connector.  Guessing on or the other is a typo?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.  I'm using MySQL ODBC Connector 8.0.31 driver.

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html

Comment: You are correct. I need to upgrade my MySQL database to v8.0 before importing it into the new database.  The changes in v8 are significant, so importing directly from 5.6 to 8.0 won't work.